# return multiple function values to main in C

Tags: c

I create the following code but the function "Count" does not return the value "x" and "y" properly because when I use the instruction "printf("Personas Mayores de edad: %d \n", Mayor);" prints 0.

throws me the following error messages:

```
main.c:23:1: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    Mayor, Menor =  Contar(Edades); 

main.c:48:13: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    return (x, y);
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Prototipado de 3 funciones
int Contar(int Edades[]);
void promEdad(int Edades[]);
void MasCantidad(int Mayor, int Menor);

//Funcion principal
int main(void) {
  int Edades[50];
  int i, Mayor, Menor;
  puts("*** Este programa simula la entrada de la edad de 50 personas (de forma aleatoria entre 1 y 50) ****\n\n");
  system("pause");

  srand(time(NULL)); //semilla para rand
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { //Genera los valores aleatorios y los asigna al arreglo
    Edades[i] = rand() % 50 + 1;
    printf("Edad generada: %d \n", Edades[i]);
  }

  Mayor, Menor = Contar(Edades); //llamado a funcion
  promEdad(Edades); //llamado a funcion

  printf("Personas Mayores de edad: %d \n", Mayor);
  printf("Personas Menores de edad: %d \n", Menor);

  MasCantidad(Mayor, Menor);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

//Definicion de funcion 1
int Contar(int Edades[]) {
  int i, x = 0, y = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { //Cont
    if (Edades[i] > 17) {
      x = x + 1;
    } else {
      y = y + 1;
    }
  }
  return (x, y);
}

//Definicion de funcion 2
void promEdad(int Edades[]) {
  int i;
  int suma = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    suma = suma + Edades[i];
  }
  printf("El promedio de edad es: %d \n", suma / 50);
}

//Definicion de funcion 3
void MasCantidad(int Mayor, int Menor) {
  if (Mayor == Menor) {
    puts("Es la misma cantidad de menores y mayores");
  } else if (Mayor > Menor) {
    puts("Hay mas mayores de edad");
  } else {
    puts("Hay mas menores de edad");
  }
}
```

Comment: C does not have multiple return values.

Comment: Next time you can save some trouble by googling for *question title site:stackoverflow.com* first before writing the question, i.e. `return multiple function values to main in C site:stackoverflow.com`, then opening the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return (x, y)` will execute the expression `x`, throw away the result, execute the expression `y`, and then return the value of the expression `y`.

To return multiple values, you will either want to use pointer arguments:

```
void foo(int *a, int *b) {
  *a = 3;
  *b = 4;
}

int main() {
  int x, y;
  foo(&x, &y);
  assert(x == 3);
  assert(y == 4);
}
```

Or use a struct:

```
struct Object {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct Object foo() {
  struct Object obj;
  obj.a = 3;
  obj.b = 4;
  return obj;
}

int main() {
  struct Object obj = foo();
  int x = foo.a;
  int y = foo.b;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, if you use a `struct` you can also pass a pointer to the struct and have your function edit it, e.g. `void foo(struct Object *ptr){ ptr->a = 3; ptr->b=4; }`
This avoids dynamically allocating extra memory if the struct is large.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Whoops. Thanks for noting. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you want to return only one value in C.

If you want to return two values you have two choices:

1/ Clean one: create a struct that contains x and y and return the struct.

2/ Dangerous: Make use of the bits contain in one int:

```
// In the callee function:
return x | (y << 16)
```

And then in the caller function

```
x = ret & 0xffff
y = ret >> 16
```

Comment: Note that option 2) depends on the size that your platform has decided to make `int`, so is not very portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to return both variables, it is really the use of pointers but with this example I simplify it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* Contar(int Edades[], int results[]) {
    int i, x = 0, y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //Hasta 3 pues solo hay 3 valores
        if (Edades[i] > 17){
            x = x + 1;
        }else{ 
            y= y + 1;
        }
    }
    results[0] = x;
    results[1] = y;
    return results;
}

int main(){
    int arrayPrueba[3];
    arrayPrueba[0] = 15; 
    arrayPrueba[1] = 18; 
    arrayPrueba[2] = 19;

    int value[2];//En este arreglo se guardaran los resultados
    //Primer array tiene las edades y en el segundo se guarda el resultado
    Contar(arrayPrueba, value);  
    printf("Mayores de Edad: %d\n", value[0]);
    printf("Menores de Edad %d\n", value[1]);
}
```